# PHP create from format not formatting time correctly

Tags: php, timestamp

I have this time string from sql `00:05:00` and I need a timestamp from it but can't seem to get it. I have also tried strtotime.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$NonBillable = '00:05:00';
$NonBillable = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $NonBillable)->getTimestamp();
echo $NonBillable;
```

Comment: Your code seems to work as it is https://3v4l.org/AU3n7

Comment: @vascowhite Yes it does i did not realize that the default date was current. so I was expecting a timestamp for 1970 00:05:00

Comment: I've updated my answer to include your expectancy.

Comment: note, it's **DATE**Time, and you're not providing a date. You'll get a timestamp of whatever date the library picks as its default (either "today", or the epoch date).

Comment: @RobertHolden If you want to deal with times rather than DateTimes (they are fundamentally different) then something similar to my Time class may help. I have found it useful for several projects. Otherwise, it may give you some pointers. https://github.com/vascowhite/Time

Answer (score 0):

```
$NonBillable = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '00:05:00');
echo $NonBillable->getTimestamp();
```

It results for me `1464480300` -> `Sun, 29 May 2016 00:05:00 GMT` because no date has been given, it uses today.

So a simple solution to this would be:

```
echo $NonBillable->getTimestamp() - time();
```